# How to orient custom canvas shape on position

Tags: javascript, canvas

in an attempt to learn javascript, I'm making an asteroids game. It's all about finished, but I wanted to get cool with the space ship.

I found this Canvas shape instruction, which creates a flying saucer, and put it inside my draw() function --

```
Ship.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(28.4, 16.9);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(28.4, 19.7, 22.9, 22.0, 16.0, 22.0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.1, 22.0, 3.6, 19.7, 3.6, 16.9);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.6, 14.1, 9.1, 11.8, 16.0, 11.8);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.9, 11.8, 28.4, 14.1, 28.4, 16.9);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(222, 103, 0)";
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw saucer top.
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(22.3, 12.0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.3, 13.3, 19.4, 14.3, 15.9, 14.3);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.4, 14.3, 9.6, 13.3, 9.6, 12.0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.6, 10.8, 12.4, 9.7, 15.9, 9.7);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.4, 9.7, 22.3, 10.8, 22.3, 12.0);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(51, 190, 0)";
    ctx.fill();
    }
```

The ship also has a pos variable, which as an array of x pos and y pos.

I'm confused as heck though, in that I don't know where I would apply pos[0] and pos[1] in the drawing, to make the space ship render where it's position is currently.

Help on this would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way in this case is probably to translate the canvas using the position instead of re-calculating every point for the shape.

For example:

```
Ship.prototype.draw = function(ctx, pos) {

    ctx.translate(pos[0], pos[1]);  // translate

    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(28.4, 16.9);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(28.4, 19.7, 22.9, 22.0, 16.0, 22.0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.1, 22.0, 3.6, 19.7, 3.6, 16.9);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(3.6, 14.1, 9.1, 11.8, 16.0, 11.8);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.9, 11.8, 28.4, 14.1, 28.4, 16.9);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(222, 103, 0)";
    ctx.fill();

    // Draw saucer top.
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(22.3, 12.0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(22.3, 13.3, 19.4, 14.3, 15.9, 14.3);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(12.4, 14.3, 9.6, 13.3, 9.6, 12.0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(9.6, 10.8, 12.4, 9.7, 15.9, 9.7);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(19.4, 9.7, 22.3, 10.8, 22.3, 12.0);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(51, 190, 0)";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.translate(-pos[0], -pos[1]);  // translate back

}
```

A tip is to render the shape isolated to an off-screen canvas then draw that canvas to your main canvas using `drawImage()` (using the off-screen canvas as an image). That would be faster and easier to maintain.